# Chef Knife-Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, chef

I'm trying to bootstrap a windows 2008 R2 Server with chef and i'm receiving this error

:"CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (0x800A0007)".

After some research i find out that i must install the "specific_install" gem and use Knife-windows gem from git but when i'm trying to install gem with this command

"gem specific_install -l https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows.git"

i'm receiving the following error :

"ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `build' for Gem::Package:Module"

What am i doing wrog?

Thank you in advance